# Uploading image to server on IOS device

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using NSMutableURlRequest to send a picture to my server. I am able to read request.body.image on the server side but when I try opening the picture, I am unable to do this (I am opening it by uploading it to amazon s3 from my server and making it public). Here is by Obj C code:

```
- (bool)sendProlilePic: (UIImage*)image {
    //We need the email and password for this request
    NSString *password = [self.keychainItem objectForKey:(__bridge id)(kSecValueData)];
    NSString *email= [self.keychainItem objectForKey:(__bridge id)(kSecAttrAccount)];

    // Create the request.
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:3000/set_profilepic"]];
    // Specify that it will be a POST request
    request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";

    // This is how we set header fields
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    //make a mutable data to store all the information
    NSMutableData *requestBodyData = [NSMutableData data];


    // add loggin information and image to requestBodyData
    NSString *stringData = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"email=%@&password=%@&image=",email,password];
    [requestBodyData appendData:[stringData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
   // NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);//convert the image
    [requestBodyData appendData:[NSData dataWithData: UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0)]];//append the image
    request.HTTPBody = requestBodyData;

    // Create url connection and fire request
    NSURLResponse * response = nil;//the raw response will be stored in this variable
    NSError * error = nil;//if an error occurs then it will be stored in this variable
    //send an http post request to the server
    NSData * data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
                                      returningResponse:&response
                                                  error:&error];
    //convert the server response into a string
    NSString *stringFromData = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    //parse the HTTP response and extract the statusCode
    NSHTTPURLResponse *HTTPResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;
    NSInteger statusCode = [HTTPResponse statusCode];

    if (error == nil)//if there is no error (server is reachable)
    {
        if(statusCode == 200){
            if(error){
                [self displayAlertWithTitle:@"Error" Content:@"Looks like we did something stupid and we're trying our best to fix it. Thank you for your patience"];
                return false;
            }else{
                return true;//if the profile picture has been uploaded, return true. Otherwise return false
            }
        }else if(statusCode == 403){
            //user is doing something wrong
            //create a UIview controller and display the error message
            [self displayAlertWithTitle:@"Error" Content:stringFromData];
            return false;

        }else{
            //something is wrong and you don't know what it is
            //create a UIview controller and display a generic error message
            [self displayAlertWithTitle:@"Error" Content:@"Server is not responding. Please try again later"];
            return false;
        }
    }else{
        //either the server is down or user's internet connection is down
        [self displayAlertWithTitle:@"Error" Content:@"Please check your internet connection. We might be updating our servers. Please try again later"];
        return false;
    }}
```

I am fairly new to objective C. Can somebody check if I'm making an obvious mistake?

Comment: You can create a Base-64 encoded NSData from your imageData.

Comment: HTTP protocol limits the kinds of character composing URI field in header, while JPEG-formed binary data can contain any characters. Furthermore, some web server implementations also limit byte length of URI field (for security reasons), so you shouldn't make up an URI with potentially large data like an image. Instead, you can use a "POST" request with a content formed in `multipart/form-data` or `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` for that purpose.